# How to use SUMIF such that the function's criterion references a range rather than a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column `T` that contains numbers with a string suffix.  I want to have a sum of all the numbers in the column (without the string), based upon whether there is a number value in a different column `X`.  In my mind, the formula should be something like this:

`SUMIF($X$[...]:$X$[...],ISNUMBER($X$[...]:$X$[...]),value(textbefore($T$[...]:$T$[...]," C",1,1,,)))`

However, this is not accepted by Excel as a valid formula.  I see lots of mention of array formulas and what not when I try to research this, but I'm not able to comprehend what the correct syntactical format should be based on what I'm reading as applicable to what I need accomplished.  Appreciate any help on this, thank you!

Additional Notes: I intend to place a value in cell Q6 (and similarly for the the other two locations as well) that shows how many `#,##0 CS / #,##0 P` remains from `PO's` that have not yet been picked.  The process flow for that translates to the invoicing step for us, i.e., a PO is not considered picked for us until an invoice has been issued, so I intend to use `column X` as the logical evaluator for this.  I am considering using `ISNUMBER()` rather than `ISBLANK()` because there is currently a practice of entering "Cancelled" in voided invoices/orders (but I would need to confirm that there not instances where valid invoice numbers are alphanumerical, or I'd have to rethink how to delineate them).

Here's a screenshot of the sheet:
[image]

Here's a screenshot with the formulas:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`SUMIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I did try it but it didn't appear to accept my input.  How should `criteria1` and `criteria_range1` be structured?  I tried `=sumifs(value(textbefore($t$13:$t$596," C",1,1,,)),$x$13:$x$596,isnumber($x$13:$x$596))` but no joy.

Comment: @Arctiic ,,, try this one `=SUM(SUBSTITUTE(T2:T50, " CS", "")+0)` ,,,, adjust cell references as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work as follows, though it's a bit clunky:

`=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(($K$3=$P$13:$P$596)*(ISNUMBER($X$13:$X$596))*($R$13:$R$596)),"#,##0")&" CS / "&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(($K$3=$P$13:$P$596)*(ISNUMBER($X$13:$X$596))*($R$13:$R$596))/$D$8,"#,##0"&" P")`

The second half is the same value only converted to a different UOM (the referenced denominator is off-screen in the screenshot).